# SQL Server : find value inside a string

Tags: sql-server

I'm using:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (X64) on Windows Server 2012 R2
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17213.0

I have the following values in a table:

[table new_value from DB usm_system_change_detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj8vd.png)

I need a query that finds the value for `txtf_dns_name=` in column 'DNS_texto' and returns only the result of it. In the example it would only be "First_Domain" and "Second_Domain"

After using the tips of colleagues, I was able to do partially:

```
declare @var varchar(max) = (select new_value
                             from usm_system_change_detail AS uscd 
                             inner join usm_system_change AS usc on uscd.id = usc.id
                             inner join usm_request ON usc.object_id = usm_request.request_id
                             where object_id = '14170' 
                               and new_value like  '%silo01.mysql.bdh%'
                               and nsp_path= 'REQ_CREATE:ADDED')

select 
    substring(substring(@var, charindex('txtf_dns_nome', @var) + 14, 99), 1, charindex(',', substring(@var, charindex('txtf_dns_nome', @var) + 14, 99)) - 1)
```

This returns:

```
silo01.mysql.bdh
```

But if I remove the where clause, I get this:

> Mensagem 245, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'f8543002' to data type int.

Comment: What version of SQL server? Please also post the SQL you tried.

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: Also... I think there is an erratum in the string you posted as the value txtf_dns_name is not in your example

Comment: Building off of Angel M. in your example string it is `txtf_dns_nome=` not `txtf_dns_name=`

Comment: Please post your attempt to use substring, and what error you got.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (X64) on Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested `substring`. As the comments stated, `txtf_dns_nome` was in the string, not `txtf_dns_name`

```
declare @var varchar(max) = '**chb_cname=,chb_ipv4=value,chb_ipv6=value,lbl_dominio=,sel_dns_zona=dominio.com.br.,table_single_records-sel_rec_single_reverso--1=Não,table_single_records-txtf_rec_single_valor--1=1.1.1.1,txta_dns_motivo=teste,txtf_dns_nome=im_am_a_legend,txtf_contact_ext=1,txtf_contact_matricula=f123456,txtf_contact_name=john@email.com**'

select substring(substring(@var,charindex('txtf_dns_nome',@var) + 14, 99),1,charindex(',',substring(@var,charindex('txtf_dns_nome',@var) + 14, 99)) - 1)
```

This basically gets the `substring` from `txtf_dns_nome` to the end of the string, and then from that string, gets the `substring` to the first comma, which leaves you with your value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Pattern as NVARCHAR(100);
SET @Pattern = 'txtf_contact_name=';

select 
    SUBSTRING(MyValue, CHARINDEX(@Pattern, MyValue) + LEN(@Pattern), CHARINDEX('=', MyValue, CHARINDEX(@Pattern, MyValue))) as R
from 
    Table_2
where 
    MyValue like '%' + @Pattern + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using `REPLACE`, `SUBSTRING`, `LEN` and `CHARINDEX`:

```
--The test string
DECLARE @testString varchar(MAX) = '**chb_cname=,chb_ipv4=value,chb_ipv6=value,lbl_dominio=,sel_dns_zona=dominio.com.br.,table_single_records-sel_rec_single_reverso--1=Não,table_single_records-txtf_rec_single_valor--1=1.1.1.1,txta_dns_motivo=teste,txtf_dns_nome=im_am_a_legend,txtf_contact_ext=1,txtf_contact_matricula=f123456,txtf_contact_name=john@email.com**'
--Local string variable to hold the reduced string
--This gets the substring starting at the character index of the string you are
--looking for a value of (txtf_dns_nome)
--Then using REPLACE we get rid of the value txtf_dns_nome= which leaves a substring
--Holding the value you want or in case it is not the last key/value, the value
--Plus the remaining string
DECLARE @reducedString varchar(MAX) = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@testString, CHARINDEX('txtf_dns_nome=', @testString), LEN(@testString) - CHARINDEX('txtf_dns_nome', @testString)), 'txtf_dns_nome=', '')
--Check to see if there is a comma, if so we want to grab the value up to the comma
--else the searched for string was the last key/value in the string so just get
--what is left
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', @reducedString) = 0 THEN @reducedString ELSE SUBSTRING(@reducedString, 0, CHARINDEX(',', @reducedString, 0)) END
```

If you need this as a table solution just do the following, I split it up into an example above to try to explain what is happening and to give you an example for testing.

TABLE Solution:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', REPLACE(SUBSTRING([YourColumn], CHARINDEX('txtf_dns_nome=', [YourColumn]), LEN([YourColumn]) - CHARINDEX('txtf_dns_nome', [YourColumn])), 'txtf_dns_nome=', '')) = 0 THEN
REPLACE(SUBSTRING([YourColumn], CHARINDEX('txtf_dns_nome=', [YourColumn]), LEN([YourColumn]) - CHARINDEX('txtf_dns_nome', [YourColumn])), 'txtf_dns_nome=', '')  
ELSE SUBSTRING(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([YourColumn], CHARINDEX('txtf_dns_nome=', [YourColumn]), LEN([YourColumn]) - CHARINDEX('txtf_dns_nome', [YourColumn])), 'txtf_dns_nome=', ''), 0, CHARINDEX(',', REPLACE(SUBSTRING([YourColumn], CHARINDEX('txtf_dns_nome=', [YourColumn]), LEN([YourColumn]) - CHARINDEX('txtf_dns_nome', [YourColumn])), 'txtf_dns_nome=', ''), 0)) 
END
FROM [dbo].[YourTable]
```

Possibly Better Table Solution as this doesn't use as many calls to the functions
and reduces the string values in the sub-query one time each:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', x.[YourColumn]) = 0 THEN x.[YourColumn] ELSE SUBSTRING(x.[YourColumn], 0, CHARINDEX(',', x.[YourColumn], 0)) END AS [YourColumn]
FROM 
(
   SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING([YourColumn], CHARINDEX('txtf_dns_nome=', [YourColumn]), LEN([YourColumn]) - CHARINDEX('txtf_dns_nome', [YourColumn])), 'txtf_dns_nome=', '') AS [YourColumn]
   FROM [dbo].[YourTable]
) AS x
```

Comment: After using the tips of colleagues, I was able to do partially: